# How can I fix undefined symbol error?

Tags: 22.04, debuild

I ran `do-release-upgrade` from 20 LTS to 22 LTS.

Some apps now execute with issue

```sh
symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0: undefined symbol: mpg123_param2
```

How I tried to fix it

```sh
$> apt source libopenmpt0
...
$> debuild
...
$>  sudo dpkg -i ./libopenmpt-build-deps_0.6.1-1_all.deb
```

All finished fine. But the issue is there.

Also

- `libmpg123-* is already the newest version (1.29.3-1build1).`

Comment: Have you tried to install the mpg123 library? Try `sudo apt-get install libmpg123-*`

Comment: Yep, `libmpg123-0 is already the newest version (1.29.3-1build1).` Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: `libmpg123.so` is in the dev package. I suggest to install the `libmpg123-dev` package.

Comment: @Harris, thanks. I have both already `-*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by installing a new version of [mpg123](http://mpg123.org/index.shtml)

```sh
$> tar -xvf mpg123-1.30.2.tar.bz2
$> cd ./mpg123-1.30.2
$> cat INSTALL

$< installation instructions here
```